# AWS EC2 g5 - Mounting disk every time when starting the instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Do we have to mount the inbuilt drives of AWS g5 instances, every time after starting and stopping the instance ?

In my case, it is unmounted every time after stopping and I will have to manually mount it on start. Is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are manually running the `mount` command, then Linux will not re-mount that volume after you stop and restart the instance. The official guide for [mounting instance store volumes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/add-instance-store-volumes.html) in EC2 has a link at the bottom to the documentation for [automatically mounting an attached volume after reboot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html#ebs-mount-after-reboot). You have to add the volume to the Linux `/etc/fstab` configuration file in order for Linux to mount the volume automatically on boot.